# Keychain: Ask password before autofill

Tags: security, password, keychain

Is it possible to have Keychain ask for the admin password before autofilling other passwords or credit card information?

I am already using keychain quite a bit. But I'm also realizing that other people use my computer occasionally and in that case, I would like my passwords to be off limits. For many of us it's not just passwords, but also credit card information that are stored in Keychain.

I am aware that with the menu bar icon, one can `Lock all Keychains`. My experience with that was, though, that it renders the computer practically unusable. Too many services need access to the keychain, like accountsd. And unless a password is typed in, the password prompt will stay on screen at all times.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to require password for keychain but here's how I handle sharing my computer:

My admin account is password protected and I have a "Guest" account setup that anyone can access without my intervention (just choose the account). It sets up a clean/empty environment every time. None of your data will be there and anything they create will not be stored.